# Select a Range of Letters

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to select row with name starting with 'A' until name starting with 'D'? And sort them alphabetically? Something like a combination of LIKE and =<> ?

Sample Table:

```
ID       Name
4001     Spartakol
4002     Tabunjong
4003     Mabini
4004     Carlos
4005     Antonio
4006     Babsy
4007     Jose
4008     David
4009     Cruz
```

Sample Output:

```
4005     Antonio
4006     Babsy
4004     Carlos
4009     Cruz
4008     David
```

with name starting with 'Cr' until name starting with 'D'

Sample Output:

```
4009     Cruz
4008     David
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Select the names from `'A'` up to, but not including `'E'`:

```
select ID, Name
from SampleTable
where Name >= 'A' and Name < 'E'
order by Name
```

As this is a plain comparison, it can use an index if you have one for that field.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: why not where Name >= 'A' and Name <= 'D' ? Because I will use it with my application where a textBox is a parameter to filter. So it will be something like textBox + 1? For example a user enter until D then the query will be like "Name >= 'A' and Name < 'D'" then all D's will not show.

Comment: @SquarePonge: Because `'D' < 'David'`, so `Name >= 'A' and Name <= 'D'` will not include any of the names starting with D (unless some is named just D). Using `Name < 'E'` includes all names starting with D, but no names starting with E.

Comment: is there any function something like D + 1?

Comment: @SquarePonge: `char(ascii('D') + 1)`

Comment: What if I want to select from x to z inclusive ? 'char(ascii('z') + 1)' returns '{' and that statement selects nothing!

Comment: @HariRam if using SQL Server Patrick's answer `where Name like '[V-Z]%';` is good. If using MySQL, and it's a relatively small dataset, you could use the SUBSTRING function to only look at the first letter: `where substring(s.LastName, 1, 1) between 'V' and 'Z'.` Just bear in mind there may be performance implications with this one.

Comment: Also, `char(ascii('z') + 1)` does work in MySQL, at least in 5.7.28 with InnoDB and utf8_general_ci collation. I have I haven't tested it in SQL Server. `like '[V-Z]%'` is neater there anyway though.

Answer (score 9):

Guffa's answer is probably the most efficient. To be complete, you could also use

```
LIKE '[a-d]%'
```

Depending on your database `COLLATION`, `LIKE` might be case sensitive or not.

Comment: mysql apparently doesn't support `[a-z]` character ranges, only `%` and `_`

Comment: @PeterCordes: the question is tagged SQL Server

Comment: Yeah, but this came up in my google search, when I was trying to find out why http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp said `[a-z]` worked, but then it didn't when I tried it, and the mysql manual didn't mention it.  So I thought I'd leave a note to let people know that wasn't portable SQL.  Doesn't make it a bad answer to *this* question, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes for mysql you can use REGEXP_LIKE to achieve the same effect, I think

Answer (score 4):

```
select id, name
from table
where LOWER(LEFT(name, 1)) between 'a' and 'd'
order by name;
```

If you want to match multiple character then use

```
select id, name
  from table
 where name >= 'Cr' 
   and (name < 'D' OR name like 'D%')
 order by name;
```

Comment: see my comment for Ilia G.

Comment: No, but giving a sluggish answer is not the goal, is it ?

Comment: @ Ilia G: not at all, just that can make the difference between 1/100 sec or 10 minute wait on a reasonably large dataset.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to select a record by **letter range of first letter** of the specific column.

```
select *output record*
from *tableName*
WHERE name LIKE '[X-Z]%'
```

- range is X to Z and '%' specify the rest of the name can be anything.

Example:

Imagine if you have a table name student with three columns like (ID, Name, Address).

```
___________________________
**ID    Name    Address**
1     Kasun   Colombo
2     Amal    Galle
___________________________

select ID,Name
from Student
WHERE name LIKE '[A-E]%'

=======================
OUTPUT
____________
**ID    Name**
2     Amal
____________
```

Answer (score 1):

select id, name
from Your Table
where LOWER(LEFT(name, 1)) between 'a' and 'd';
order by name;

Answer (score 1):

Here's another simpler solution

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name BETWEEN "A" AND "E" ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it using BETWEEN, LIKE & a combination of sub-queries.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE name BETWEEN 
(SELECT name FROM table_name 
WHERE name LIKE 'A%' 
ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 0,1) 
AND 
(SELECT name FROM table_name 
WHERE name LIKE 'D%' 
ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 0,1) 
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_name
where left(name,1) between 'A' and 'D'
order by name;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select *
from Foo
where substring(name, 1, 1) between 'a' and 'd'
order by name
```

Comment: -1: Perfect example on how to defeat indexes and any kind of optimisation. Never filter on an expression when you can avoid it !

Comment: Agree with previous comment.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez this solution has the advantage that it will work up to Z, which the accepted answer won't. Your answer is better but is not portable. This one may be acceptable, depending on your RDMS and dataset.

Comment: `where name between 'a' and char(ascii('z') + 1)` works in MySQL. This is on the other side of the expression so should only be evaluated once.