# Basic SQL Query, I am newbie

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just started my database and query class on Monday. We met on Monday and just went over the syllabus, and on Wednesday the network at school was down so we couldn't even do the power point lecture. Right now I am working on my first homework assignment and I am almost finished but I am having trouble on one question.

Here is is...

> Write a SELECT statement that returns one column from the Customers table named FullName that joins the LastName and FirstName columns.
>   Format the columns with the last name, a comma, a space, and the first name like this:
>   Doe, John
>   Sort the result set by last name in ascending sequence.
>   Return only the contacts whose last name begins with letters from M to Z.

Here is what I have so far...

```
USE md0577283
SELECT FirstName,LastName
FROM Customers
ORDER BY LastName,FirstName
```

My question is how do I format is Lastname, FirstName like the professor wants and how do I only select names M-Z?

If someone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you.

PS With all do respect, I didn't ask for the answer I asked for a nudge in the right direction so why the down vote guys?

Comment: search for LIKE ....

Comment: Yup, I hadn't learned about that statement yet, Once I started reading farther in the chapter is started making sense. Thank Youy

Comment: The title has not useful information. I advice changing it to something more meaninful like "filter names with starting letter SQL Query" or something like that.
About the downvotes, it happens to us all when we start using stackoverflow. But the problem is not really if you asked for the answer or not. I think is more about how it was written(the question in general) and that this question is surely already answered in this forum if you have done a little bit more of reasearch.

Comment: An example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513366/select-a-range-of-letters

Comment: Something nice: https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/18/building-community-inclusivity-stack-overflow/?cb=1
So conclusion, don't feel bad, you're a newbie and only got -3? that's more than most of us can do. I also felt very bad about my first posts but I did got better and asking questions here.

Answer (score 2):

```
USE md0577283
SELECT LastName + ', ' + FirstName FullName
FROM Customers
WHERE LastName LIKE '[M-Z]%'
ORDER BY LastName,FirstName
```

Comment: should be `LIKE '[M-Z]%'` ?

Comment: Yeah probably, don't have SQL server handy here. Updated.

Comment: Presumably, because the query was wrong before your edit - it's been removed now.

Comment: It is not educational to give a full answer to a school homework. I would have just given a direction, eg. Look for like expression etc. by the way I did not downvote.

Comment: Ok Guys thank you, that got it.  I am reading the chapter right now as I go and its making sense. I just hadn't learned about the LIKE statement yet.

Comment: And gba I agree, I am not looking for handouts I was excepting a gently nudge in the right direction, but thanks to all anyway.  Here is what I came up with..

USE md0577283
SELECT LastName + ',' + FirstName
AS FullName
FROM Customers
WHERE LastName LIKE '[M-Z]%'
ORDER BY LastName,FirstName ASC

Comment: @gba I realized it may be frowned upon by the large majority here, but I'm not here to impose my morals on others. I'm here to ask and answer questions about programming, regardless of whether they are homework assignments or real world issues. If the OP doesn't bother to do their research, they're not going to do well. However, thats their perogative.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add two things:  create an expression to return the name in the requested format 
 (`LastName + ", " + FirstName as Name`)

USe a "where clause" to filter what is returned: where LastName >= "M"  and LastName <= "Z" perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Simply write like this.

If you want to get names from m to z.

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName 
FROM Customers 
WHERE FirstName between 'M%' and 'Z%' 
ORDER BY LastName, FirstName
```

If you want to get names from m and z only.

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName 
FROM Customers 
WHERE FirstName LIKE 'M%' OR FirstName LIKE 'Z%' 
ORDER BY LastName, FirstName
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT last_name, first_name,
       CONCAT (last_name, ', ', first_name)
              AS full_name
FROM customers
WHERE last_name REGEXP '^[m|z]'
ORDER BY last_name ASC
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?