# LIke thru change is needed

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
AND "Diagnosis_Codes"."Diagnosis_Code" LIKE 'I10%'
```

THis will get me the codes that start with I10.

How do i get a range like we need starts with I10 thru I15?

Comment: `where column >= 'I10' and column < 'I16'`

Comment: @jarlh Does that work for text?

Comment: Yes, it does. Try and see!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select a Range of Letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513366/select-a-range-of-letters)

Answer (score 10):

you can use below condition

```
LIKE 'I1[0-5]%'
```

Comment: Probably the best SQL Server answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [LEFT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx)

```
AND (LEFT("Diagnosis_Codes"."Diagnosis_Code",3) BETWEEN 'I10' AND 'I15')
```